# Why is it not possible to overload the reference operator (&)?

Tags: rust, reference, operator-overloading

Why is it possible to overload the dereferencing operator `*` (and implicitly `.`) using the traits `Deref` and `DerefMut`, but it's not possible to overload `&`?

I'm asking out of curiosity. I don't have a specific use case. I want to understand the asymmetry between `&` and `*`. They are so closely related, almost inverses of each other, but only one can be overloaded.

Here's a use case, for those who wanted one. It's quite contrived, and vague. If `*` accesses the value of a smart pointer, `&` could create a smart pointer, so that a particular type defaults to a smart pointer not a reference.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you may want to do with this? If it's not imperative to the question, then solely for my curiosity.

Comment: Overloading `*` is useful to make transparent smart-pointers. Overloading `&` however is more dubious. What would be the use case? C++ allows that, but it's considered bad practice.

Comment: I voted to close as "opinion based" because the only real answer one can give is the somewhat-circular "because the language does not allow it". Talking about *why* the language does not allow it is unlikely to be answerable without appealing to opinion, like "it wouldn't be useful" or "it would be confusing".

Comment: If you have some scenario in mind where overloading `&` would be desirable, I encourage you to ask about *that*; it's likely you are doing something very odd and the resulting answers might be enlightening for more than one of us.

Comment: @trentcl I see where you're coming from, but I think it's only opinion-based in so far as any language design choice is down to the opinion of the designers. If someone who knows what the actual thought process was feels like answering, great. If not, that's fine, I just won't get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess ...

For any type `T`, there are many pointer types: references (shared and exclusive), as well as various smart pointers (`Box`, `Cell`, `Rc` etc.). These can all be dereferenced. That is, dereferencing is many to one, which can be completely defined by a single operator `*`. Meanwhile, creating a pointer type is one to many, which can't be defined by a single operator `&`.